# How does a file downloader know where the file begins?

Tags: networking, ip

Suppose, I'm downloading a file over HTTP protocol. The packets containing the fragments of the file may arrive in any order. Then, how does the downloader know which packet is the first in the order? I was looking at the fields of an HTTP packet [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) and didn't find any "Sequence Number" field.

After giving a little thought to the question, I came to the conclusion that HTTP is a layer 7 protocol and depends on the protocols of the underlying layers. TCP, being a layer 4 protocol, provides HTTP with this service of sequencing the data as the TCP header does have a Sequence number ([Found it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)).

But, I'm not sure if this theory is correct so I want to ask the experts about it. Is there any other mechanism in place to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So actually, if there is no interruption, the file is being downloaded with a singe TCP connection. So your downloader does not even know it's fragmented.

You can use wireshark and see [this example here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=http_with_jpegs.cap.gz)

[image]

If the connection drops or if the download manager wants to split the download so it can use 4 connections, for example, it has to set the [RANGE header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requestsz):

```
GET /z4d4kWk.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: i.imgur.com
Range: bytes=0-1023
```

In this case, the answer would be

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range: bytes 0-1023/146515
Content-Length: 1024
```

Answer (score 1):

You guessed it. [From RFC 2616 section 1.4 Overall Operation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-1.4), emphasis added:

> HTTP communication **usually takes place over TCP/IP connections.** The
> default port is TCP 80 [19], but other ports can be used. This does
> not preclude HTTP from being implemented on top of any other protocol
> on the Internet, or on other networks. **HTTP only presumes a reliable
> transport;** any protocol that provides such guarantees can be used;
> the mapping of the HTTP/1.1 request and response structures onto the
> transport data units of the protocol in question is outside the scope
> of this specification.

"reliable transport" is networking jargon for "delivers the data without loss (unless signalled), duplication/replay, alteration, or misordering".

And similarly HTTPS runs over TLS (formerly SSL), which builds on TCP and provides essentially the same service (reliable byte-stream transport) but with the added properties of confidentiality and integrity (unless signalled error) even against intelligent attackers rather than merely natural errors and faults.
There are performance differences, but AFAIK the only service differences are that TLS doesn't provide TCP's 'urgent' pointer aka out-of-band, or separate close per direction like TCP's 'half-closed' states, and HTTP/HTTPS doesn't need those.

Comment: This answer is great except the last paragraph makes it sound like TLS is its own transport instead of pointing out that TLS uses TCP, so your reliable transport is still TCP.

Comment: @Spiff: good point. adjusted.